The identity of the variational equation (ODE)
Consider the nonautonomous system:
$\dot{x}=f(t,x)$,
$s(t, t_0,x_0)$ is the solution trajectory  starting from $s(t_0,t_0,x_0)=x_0$.
I wonder why $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Vert s(\tau, t, x)\Vert ^p + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Vert s(\tau, t, x)\Vert^p f(t, x) \equiv 0$, where $p>1$.
Thanks in advance.

Where did you see that identity?

I see the identity from DOI: 10.1109/TAC.2019.2958481.  The last part of the proof of Proposition A.1.

By replacing th left $f(t,x) = \dot x(t)$ you see the total differential wrt to $t_0$, expressed by the derivatives  wrt to start values,  the fixed end value at $t=\tau$ given.
The time backwards solution yielding the start value $x_0(t_0)$ is of course another way to present solutions e.g. in astronomy.
The time forward presentation was fixed in the  by the founders of mechanics who were teachers for the artillery.
The double forward-backward description arose from the theory of estimating future values in stock markets involving noise terms.

Thanks. But I still don't understand why the total differential wrt to $t_0$ equals 0. Is it because $x_0$ is a fixed point?
